# Multiple webs on a server using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

Is there any way to configure Capistrano for deploying many webs on a server?
I would like to have a project on port 80 an other project on port 1000 and manage each one with different dbs.

Comment: The answer is "yes" - I do that all the time.  Do you have a specific problem?

And surely the port numbers should be irrelevant to Capistrano.

Answer (score 0):

As Leonm said, the port numbers are completely irrelevant - you configure your application and web server environment with multiple virtual hosts, and simply deploy to the vhost webroot directory.

Answer (score 0):

For Apache, you can get some help here.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/

I am hosting my own VPS (multiple) with Apache2 + Passenger (mod_rails) + vhost config.
Share some more specific details if you wish to.

Answer (score 0):

My capistrano script looks something like this (I trimmed some stuff for IP safety)
http://pastie.textmate.org/699537

then I have vhosts configured for each of these folders where app gets deployed.
apache makes it a breeze.